# Is it possible to stream android phone screen to another android phone using MediaRecorder or MediaProjection?

Tags: android

I want to **share a phone screen to another phone over the Wifi** by the help of **MediaRecorder & Media Projection APIs**. My target is API-21 and above.

**I have few questions:**

1. How can I achieve it? Need few guidelines.
2. Does it involves networking programming to do so?

Comment: Show some code then we can help,
Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this feature using Socket and Media Projection API. The basic idea is to create bitmap of your screen by Media Projection API( have a look on the reference project over github [Screen Capture Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture) ), now send the stream of bitmaps by using Socket. ([Example of socket implementation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java)).

After this setup your ready to stream your screenshot bitmaps over socket, little bit of lag can be found but it will meet your requirement.

So if you go with this approach then network is needed. But if you implement peer to peer Wifi connection then you can replace Socket with Wifi P2P, in that case no Internet connection is needed.

Do let me know if this help.

Cheers!!